# Unable to dismiss TextField that has Keyboard Type as Decimal Pad in SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui

I have linked the focused field with @FocusState private var priceIsFocused: Bool but still the keyboard won't dismiss itself. On clicking the "Done" Button, the keyboard flashes for a second and comes right back.

```
TextField("Amount", value: $billAmount, formatter: NumberFormatter())
                                    .focused($priceIsFocused)
                                    .keyboardType(.decimalPad)
                                    .autocapitalization(.none)
                                    .disableAutocorrection(true)
                                    .focusedLegacy($focusedFieldBill, equals: .itemAmount)
                                    .toolbar {
                                        ToolbarItemGroup(placement: .keyboard) {
                                            Spacer()
                                            Button {
                                                priceIsFocused = false
                                            } label: {
                                                Text("Done")
                                            }
    
                                        }
                                    }
```

Comment: What happens if you remove `focusedLegacy`? Is that affecting it somehow?

Comment: Works fine without `.focusedLegacy`. Xcode 13.4 / iOS 15.5

Comment: ah! Thank you. focusedLegacy used to trigger it back again.